# Taking out double letters

Tags: c++

My program generates random consonant or vowel chosen by the user. It then searches a dictionary for the words and displays them. What i want happen is for double letters to be changed so they aren't the same anymore with out having to ask the user again.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


char response;
int letter;
int letter2;
int n;
char  result[8];
string a = " ";

string array1 [70549];
string array2[70549] ;
string array3[70549] ;
string array4[70549] ;
string array5[70549] ;
string array6[70549] ;
string array7[70549] ;
string array8[70549] ;
string array9[70549] ;
string array10[70549] ;

char test = 'a';
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

  int main()
{
for (int a =0; a<8; a++)
{
cout<< "Consonant (c) or vowel(v)?" << endl;
cin >> response; 


{


if ( 'c' == response ) 
{
    srand (time(0));
    letter =  (rand() %21);
    n ++;


        switch (letter)         //seleccts random const
        {
        case 0: 
            cout << "b" << endl;
            result[n] = 'b';
            break;

        case 1: 
            cout << "c" << endl;
            result[n] = 'c';
            break;

        case 2:  
            cout << "d" << endl;
            result[n] = 'd';
            break;

        case 3: 
            cout << "f" << endl;
            result[n] = 'f';
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "g" << endl;
            result[n] = 'g';
            break;

        case 5: 
            cout << "h"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'h';
            break;

        case 6: 
            cout << "j" << endl;
            result[n] = 'j';
            break;

        case 7: 
            cout << "k" << endl;
            result[n] = 'k';
            break;

        case 8: 
            cout << "l" << endl;
            result[n] = 'l';
            break;

        case 9: 
            cout << "m" << endl;
            result[n] = 'm';
            break;

        case 10: 
            cout << "n" << endl;
            result[n] = 'n';
            break;

        case 11: 
            cout << "p" << endl;
            result[n] = 'p';
            break;

        case 12: 
            cout << "q" << endl;
            result[n] = 'q';
            break;

        case 13: 
            cout << "r" << endl;
            result[n] = 'r';
            break;

        case 14: 
            cout << "s"<< endl;
            result[n] = 's';
            break;

        case 15: 
            cout << "t" << endl;
            result[n] = 't';
            break;

        case 16: 
            cout << "v"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'v';
            break;

        case 17: 
            cout << "w"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'w';
            break;

        case 18: 
            cout << "x" <<endl;
            result[n] = 'x';
            break;

        case 19: 
            cout << "y"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'y';
            break;

        case 20: 
            cout << "z"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'z';
            break;
        }
}

   else if ('v' == response)
{
    srand (time(0));
    letter2 = ( rand() %4);
    n++;

    switch (letter2)                                      //selects random vowel
        {
        case 0: 
            cout <<  "a"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'a';
            break;

        case 1: 
            cout << "e" <<endl;
            result[n] = 'e';
            break;

        case 2: 
            cout << "i"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'i';
            break;

        case 3: 
            cout << "o"<< endl;
            result[n] = 'o';
            break;

        case 4: 
            cout << "u" << endl;
            result[n] = 'u';

        }   
    }
     else if (  response != 'c' || 'v')
        {
            cout << "Invalid, please choose 'c' or 'v'"<< endl;
            cin >> response;
        }

}


}



cout<<endl<< "Your letters are";




for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    cout << result[i];
    cout << " ";
}



 ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\words.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 70549; ++i)
    {
        file >> array1[i];
    }
}

    int l = 0;




    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array1[i].find(result[1]);

            if (found != std::string::npos)
                array2[i] = array1[i];              
        }   


    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array2[i].find(result[2]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array3[i] = array2[i];              
        }

    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array3[i].find(result[3]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array4[i] = array3[i];
        }

    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array4[i].find(result[4]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array5[i] = array4[i];              
        }

    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array5[i].find(result[5]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array6[i] = array5[i];              
        }

    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array6[i].find(result[6]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array7[i] = array6[i];              
        }

    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array7[i].find(result[7]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array8[i] = array7[i];              
        }

    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array8[i].find(result[8]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array9[i] = array8[i];              
        }


cout << "Your words are: ";
    for ( int i=0; i< (sizeof(array2)/sizeof(*array2));i ++)
        if (!array9[i].empty())
        {
        cout << array9[i] << ", ";
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but `std::unique` comes to mind.

Comment: I don't want them deleted, I still need 8 letters. I just don't want any doubles

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You showed us your program, told you what you wanted to do, and then didn't ask us a question. What issue are you having? Have you worked out an algorithm for doing this? If not, why not ask us to help you do so? If you have, what issue are you having implementing it?

Comment: No i haven't worked out how to do it, sorry.

Comment: Don't call srand() more than once in your program. Doing that actually produces a very predictable randomness. It's probably not much of an issue in small game like this, but in more important programs, that could lead to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Also, your big switch table can be replaced by indexing into an array of char: `char[] consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"; result[n] = consonants[rand() % 21]`. Likewise with the vowels.

Comment: ouch.. really bad style..

Comment: @ Karthik T Look, if you're not going to help, please don't comment.

Comment: @LieRyan, And in more serious programs (or any, really), you'd use the handy tools in `<random>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general pieces of advice:

- Use a 2D array of strings like `string sa[10][70549];`
- Don't call srand() repeatedly. You only need to seed once. (from Lie Ryan above)
- Use char arrays instead of those nasty switch blocks. (Ryan correct here again)
- You have a bug for the vowel selection (called % 4, not % 5, so you'd never see a 'u').
- Using both `a` and `n` as position trackers is bad and looks like a bug above.
- `else if (  response != 'c' || 'v')` is also a bug; you mean to say `if (response != 'c' && response != 'v')`, but this is actually redundant given your tests above. Just use `else { ... }`.
- To prevent 2 identical consecutive letters (lazy way), in each letter generation block past a/n == 0, loop the random generator until it gets a result different from the previous character.

This program is severely bloated to the point where people will be reluctant to help you due to the burden of just scanning through the code. This looks like a homework assignment for an introductory programming class. You have enough misconceptions about how things work that you should probably spend some time reading some beginner-level books and getting some 1-on-1 help from a TA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's related to your issue, but this piece of code is probably incorrect:

```
 else if (  response != 'c' || 'v')
    {
        cout << "Invalid, please choose 'c' or 'v'"<< endl;
        cin >> response;
    }
```

the if statement here will always return true, because it is saying the following:

```
if ((response != 'c') || 'v')
```

In C++, a variable which is nonzero is always considered true and a zero is considered false.  In this case, 'v' has a non-zero character value (keeping in mind chars are basically just formatted (usually) 8-bit numbers).  You should write either:

```
else if (response != 'c' && response != 'v')
```

Or

```
else if (!(response == 'c' || response == 'v'))
```

Alternatively, you could turn the whole if ('c')/else if ('v')/else if (!('c' || 'v')) block into a switch statement, which would probably be easier to read anyway.